# Chart.js line doesn't fit in

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

The line which consist of points with maximum doesn't fit in chart... I tried to use responsive, edit height - all the same.

[image]

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

var colors = ['#3e95cd', '#8e5ea2', '#3cba9f', '#e8c3b9', '#c45850'];

var datasets = [];

for (var id in data) {
    datasets.push({ 
        data: Object.values(data[id].items),
        label: data[id].name,
        borderColor: colors.pop(),
        fill: false
    }) 
}

window.myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: Object.keys(data[1].items),
        datasets: datasets,
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: _DATE.clone().subtract(_PERIOD, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + _DATE.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Without your HTML and CSS it is difficult to tell what exactly goes wrong. Do you have a more complete example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the height of the canvas

For example:

```
<div style="height: 200px" id="chart"> </div>
```

or in your css file.

I hope this helps.